# Prolog Recursive Method

Tags: recursion, prolog

So I am writing a database that contains the rule `waywest(X,Y)`. `waywest` takes 2 buildings that are along a street and returns where or not the building `X` is more than one building west of building `Y`. I have:

```
waywest(X,Y) :- not(west(X,Y)).
waywest(X,Y) :- not(west(X,Z)) , waywest(Z,Y).
```

This is a method that recursively loops through using the fact `west(X,Y)`, where building `X` is west of building `Y`. I keep getting this existence error and debugging doesn't work either.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: What Prolog are you using? You should use `\+` rather than `not` since `\+` is the ISO standard for "not provable". Not all Prolog's support `not/1`. But you haven't said what Prolog is telling does not exist. *I keep getting this existence error and debugging doesn't work either* is, quite frankly, a vague problem statement.

Comment: Negative logic causes several issues. When you say, `\+ west(X, Y)` (or `not(west(X,Y))` as you have written it), this succeeds if `west(X, Y`) is not provable. However, it just so happens that it is provable because it is true for some values of `X` and `Y`. So this line will generally fail unless `X` and/or `Y` are instantiated in such a way that no facts match.

Comment: @lurker my apologies for the vague problem statement. I got an existence error (which I fixed somehow) and that the debugger would start off with giving the error and not do any iterations

Comment: The existence error should tell you exactly what predicate it thinks you called that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you programmed it, you can only use it to disprove facts, according to the documentation of not in swi-prolog:

> not(:Goal)
>   True if Goal cannot be proven. Retained for compatibility only. New code should use +/1.

Moreover I would discourage the use of NOT at all at the beginning of Prolog, because it's not (sic!) working as you might intend/expect in the beginning.

If I understood you problem correctly, this should also do the trick:

```
west(a,b).
west(b,c).
west(c,d).
west(d,e).

waywest(X,Z) :-
   west(X,Y),
   west(Y,Z).
waywest(X,Z) :-
   west(X,Y),
   waywest(Y,Z).
```

If we now check it we get as expected:

```
?- waywest(X,Y).
X = a, Y = c ;
X = b, Y = d ;
X = c, Y = e ;
X = a, Y = d ;
X = a, Y = e ;
X = b, Y = e ;
false.
```

Comment: I agree that the negative logic in the OP's code causes problems. But their definition of `waywest(X, Y)` is that `X` is *more than one building* west of `Y`. So `X = a` and `Y = b`, for example, is not a valid solution.

Comment: @lurker thx for pointing that out. I apparently misunderstood it, fixxed it in the code.

Comment: when testing, I get `ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: waywest/2 (DWUM could not correct goal)`

Comment: This error shows that you didn't load the file, where you wrote your rules and facts.

If your file is named "file.pl" and in the correct folder, you first need to use consult(file) or equivalent variants of that...

Comment: @Ben373 I have changed it the code to:  `waywest(X,Y) :- \+ west(X,Y).`  `waywest(X,Y) :- west(Z,Y) , waywest(X,Z).`

Comment: @Rafael_Jeffery changing it to that uses negative logic again, and that's not a good thing. Why do you gravitate to that approach? `\+ west(X,Y)` succeeds if `west(X, Y)` is not provable. The solution provided in this answer is a much better solution, and more general.